# .htaccess is read but redirect not working

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, mod-wsgi

I am using `apache` + `django` + `mod_wsgi` as server. My goal is to redirect non-`www` url to `www` url.

I have the `mod_rewrite` enabled: when executing the command `Module rewrite already enabled`, I have

> Module rewrite already enabled

The `site.conf` in `sites-available` reads

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases

  ServerName  www.<site-name>.com
  RedirectMatch ^http://<site-name>.com/(.*)$ http://www.<site-name>.com/$1

</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/<site-name>/app>
AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://<site-name>.com"
</Directory>
```

The `.htaccess` file is located in the `/var/www/<site-name>/app` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If I put random code in `.htaccess`, the site will throw `500 error`, but the redirect never works (it behaves in the following way instead):

- Typing in `site-name.com` will not trigger redirect;
- under `site-name.com`, clicking links (generated by `reverse()` function) will not trigger redirect;
- Directly typing in `site-name.com/morestuff` will trigger redirect to `www.site-name.com/morestuff`.

---

Good that I can use @Finbarr's answer to achieve what I wanted. But then I am still interested in what leads to the above redirect behavior.

Comment: You would potentially need a ``ServerAlias`` for ``<site-name>.com`` in the ``VirtualHost`` else it may not even use that ``VirtualHost`` to handle the non www host name. Instead it may get handled by whatever is the first ``VirtualHost`` in the Apache config, which could be a different one if you have more than one. Either way, I would recommend the answer already given of creating a separate ``VirtualHost`` just for the redirect.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton: I did have it before, but I just deleted the ServerAlias prior to posting the question. At the moment, I use @Finbarr's answer, in which case `site-name.com` is individually a `VirtualHost`, therefore aliasing to that url is probably not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I wouldnt modify the .htaccess file to do this when you have access to the conf file. I would create a separate virtualhost entry for the redirect and leave the main site virtualhost as normal. A typical redirect would look like this in the conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.yoursite.com
Redirect 301 / http://yoursite.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Great, just tried it and it works! Thanks, and will mark as answer.